want nolint comment to ignore redefines-builtin-id error
In my Golang code, am using an interface function signature, ZRemRangeByScore, from go-redis, that defines parameter names "min" and "max". With a new version of the revive linter, using this interface with the same parameter names now causes lint errors such as "redefines-builtin-id: redefinition of the built-in function min (revive)". Other variants of this lint error differ only by the function name in the error message.
I asked ChatGPT, and did search engine queries, trying to find the //nolint comment that tells revive to ignore this error. The only answer I got from either ChatGPT or the serch engine queries appears to be wrong, namely to use the comment
"//nolint:redefines-builtin-id"
I believe this is wrong because a) it causes a warning message "Found unknown linters in //nolint directives redefines-builtin-id" and b) the code that causes lint errors before adding this //nolint directive still causes the same lint errors.
When I told ChatGPT this //nolint directive was wrong, the response was an apology and to use the parameter file for revive. Unfortunately, the build system I am using makes changing this parameter file difficult or impossible, since revive is called on my behalf by code I do not own.
Rather than break the interface by using different parameter names from those in the go-redis function's signature, I'd like to know if there is a simple fix involving a different //nolint directive. Or if it is necessary to break the interface, it would be nice to know that is the only remedy before I do it.

Unless I am missing something (some code would be helpful!), I do not understand why you think you have to break the interface.  The significant properties of function arguments in an interface are the position and type of those arguments, not the names.  It isn't possible to be sure without seeing your code (sic!!). Still, I think you should be able to use different but appropriate names for those arguments in your interface implementation to avoid redefining min/max and keep the linter happy.

I can't share code for business reasons but I appreciate the information about interfaces. That is not the optimal solution but it will do.

You could reduce the code to a minimal example, obfuscated to provide a meaningful illustration of the problem without disclosing anything sensitive.  I already posted a more detailed explanation as an answer (which also shows how you can post code without necessarily sharing specifics); it would be helpful if you could accept that if it has helped you.  Thanks.

Unless I am missing something (some code would be helpful!), I do not understand why you think you have to break the interface.
The significant properties of function arguments in an interface are the position and type of those arguments, not the names.
It isn't possible to be sure without seeing your code. Still, I think you should be able to use different but appropriate names for those arguments in your interface implementation to avoid redefining min/max and keep the linter happy.
e.g.
type Fooable interface {
   Foo(len int, max string) // note these names will upset the linter if used in an implementation
}

type fooable struct {}

// Foo implements Fooable.  Note the parameter names differ from those in
// the interface declaration, but the position and types match, so the
// interface is satisfied
func (f fooable) Foo(x int, y string) {
  // ...
}

In fact, to emphasise that the names of the parameters are not relevant to the interface contract, they are, in fact, entirely optional. e.g. this is an equally valid declaration of the above hypothetical Fooable interface:
type Fooable interface {
   Foo(int, string)
}

However, if any_ parameter is named, then ALL must be named per method.
i.e., you can have one method in an interface declared with unnamed parameters and another with named parameters. But you cannot have any method with some parameters named but not all.
In general, I think it is a good idea to name parameters.  The exception, of course, would be if the purpose and intent of the parameters is clear enough without names.
